# Value is not getting inserted in the Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an account in Firebase and I have created a project by the name "Fieldglass".

Now the on clicking on the database tab in the firebase account I get a database named: `fieldglass-aeca7`

Now I want to insert values inside this. I have written a code for it in the `OnCreate()` function.

```
final CountDownLatch sync = new CountDownLatch(1);

        DatabaseReference db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("fieldglass-aeca7");
        String userId=db.push().getKey();
        User u=new User("shikher","shikher.mishra@yahoo.com");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.child(userId).setValue(u).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                sync.countDown();

            }
        });
        try{
            sync.await();

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("there is an exception here in sync.await()");
        }
```

Now after running this code the values are not getting inserted into the database at the console.
How can I insert the values into the database of Firebase?

The user class is:

```
package com.example.hsports.galleryusingimageswitcher; /**
 * Created by I324671 on 11/7/2016.
 */

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;




public class User {

public String name;
 public String email;

 public User(){
 }
 public User(String name,String email)
 {
  this.name=name;
  this.email=email;
 }

}
```

Comment: are you sure that the app is permitted to write in the database? post your database rules if you're not sure.

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}    these are my database rules which I have specified under the Rules tab in firebase

Comment: hm. can you post the `User` class?

Comment: yeah I have added the user class in the edited question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the getter methods for the `User` model class's properties.

from [Read and Write Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write)

> Pass a custom Java object, if the class that defines it has a default constructor that takes no arguments **and has public getters** for the properties to be assigned.

```
public class User {
    public String name;
    public String email;

    public User() {}
    public User(String name,String email) {
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }
}
```

This should work. :)

Comment: But in my code I am not using the getter methods then how will this work for me?

Comment: @shikher.mishra it's required for the class to have public getter methods so the properties can be assigned by `setValue` method. [read more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)